# Score links on top-users tag page should show just answers or questions

Tags: feature-request, top-users, tag-score

The top user tag pages (e.g. [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/feature-request/topusers)) are split into Answerers and Askers and there are different scores and Q/A totals for each.  Clicking on the link (question total) for either points you to a search page for the tag and user (e.g. [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:22656%20%5Bfeature-request%5D)).

If you clicked on that link, you might (or at least I often) want to see just the questions or just the answers provided by that user.  It'd be nice to tweak the pre-formed search to include `is:answer` or `is:question` as appropriate.